# How do i install an app into a dhis2 instance for the first time?

Tags: dhis-2

I am trying to install an app into my dhis2 v2.28 instance. I install the app from the app store on the app management platform but after installation, i cannot find the app on my app list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When installing custom apps in DHIS2, the system will generate a new authority for the app. This authority will have the format "See_< app-name >".

I believe your user have not been granted the appropriate authority to access the app, which is required to both see and access it.

You can add the authority by creating or editing roles in the user app.

Hope this helps!